# How do I get an infinite vertically scrolling image in CSS?

Tags: css, css-animations

I'm trying to add an infinitely vertically scrolling image much like Adam Whitcroft's fantastic [landing page](http://adamwhitcroft.com/batch/). I've looked at his source code, but I can't figure out how he pulled it off. The idea is that the "I'm a scientist" text will appear over the image.

My current code is:

```
<div class="ani">
    <div class="container">
            <img src="img/Gene.png" alt="Scrolling Genes" />
        </div> 
<h3> I'm a scientist. </h3>
    <p> I worked at.... </p>
```

The CSS for the "ani" class is:

```
.ani {
background: url(img/Gene.png);
color:#ecf2f9;
text-align:center;
-webkit-animation:bgscroll 20s infinite linear;
}
```

And for "container":

```
    .header .container {
    max-width:400px;
}
```

That code was (shamefully) taken from the site I mentioned above. I *can't*, for the life of me, figure out how to create a scrolling image above the text.

Thanks *very* much in advance.

Comment: Can you tell us more about what this does now?  Perhaps set up a jsfiddle?

Comment: Use javascript to change the pixel coordinates of your tag/image.  Keep your y coordinate constant and vary your x coordinate.  Do this in a loop.

Comment: The site that he's referencing uses CSS to achieve this effect, not javascript.

Comment: David Barsky, if you found either of the two answers below helpful, please accept one of them.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your code was good. You just forget to define your animation.

```
@-webkit-keyframes bgscroll {
    from {background-position:0 0;}
    to {background-position:0 -520px;}
}
```

Here is a sample of what you want : http://codepen.io/joe/pen/hdoIk

Obviously you have to change the picture with yours and define the good height to the animation.

For a full browser support, don't forget to add all the CSS prefix vendor.
More informations here : http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_animations.asp
( -wekbit -moz -o )

You can do it easily with just pasting your code on : http://prefixr.com

Hope it helps.

Comment: @DavidBarsky: If you accept this answer as being correct, then you might want to mark it as such. ;]

Comment: Is there a way to make it continuous..like animate to top and then back to bottom?

Comment: To get this work make sure you have background-repeat: repeat, and no background-size attribute

Comment: Could you please update the links, thanks